# reconfigure unity-2d after downgrade

Tags: apt, unity-2d, gconf

I tried enabling HUD in unity following the instructions at http://techhamlet.com/2012/01/how-to-install-the-new-hud-in-ubuntu-12-04-and-11-10/, but when I had finished, I found that it doesn't work for me since I'm using Unity 2D (my fault, I should have checked it first).

Now, I've downgraded to the normal (supported) version of Unity, but unity-2d isn't starting. When I try to run `unity-2d-launcher`, it exits with the following output:

```
    unity-2d-launcher: [FATAL] Settings schema 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher' is not installed
```

...and `unity-2d-panel` gives:

```
    unity-2d-panel: [FATAL] Settings schema 'com.canonical.Unity.Panel' is not installed
```

I tried using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-2d` but it still doesn't work.

How do I reconfigure unity-2d to make it start working, or do I need to manually do `sudo apt-get remove` and then `sudo apt-get install`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run `sudo apt-get purge unity-2d*` instead of `sudo apt-get remove unity-2d*`, and then install the unity-2d*.
If this doesn't work try to create a new user, with this pure user it'll maybe works.

Good luck, I hope it'll works.